# How to create a search bar that drops down a list of items from a SQL database

Tags: javascript, html, css, search, dropdown

How to create a search bar like on youtube or many other sites that searches a database and only displays a few results overlaying the rest of the site.

I have already searched google and youtube for tutorials and some help with searching a database, and others with how to create a search bar. But for some reason, I cannot find one that helps me figure out how to display the items in a drop-down that overlays the rest of the page and doesn't displace the content. I have also tried you the CSS display: none; but as soon as that is set to display: block; with javascript, for example, the content is displaced. Thank you in advance.

I have tried to use this javascript for the table:

```
function search() {
var input, filter, found, table, tr, td, i, j;
input = document.getElementById("myInput");
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
table = document.getElementById("myTable");
table.style.display = "block";
tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    for (j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {
        if (td[j].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if (found) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
        found = false;
    } else if (!tr[i].id.match('^tableHeader')) {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

}

and my HTML is as follows:

```
        <table id="myTable">
            <tr>
                {% for key, value in list.items() %}
                <td>{{ key|e }</td>
                <td id="name">{{ value|e }}</td>
                <td>
                    <form class="form-signin ajax" action="/signIn" method="post" data-replace="#res" role="form">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="watchlist" value="Watchlist" onclick="writeToCell (this.id)" id="{{ key|e }}">
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
```

I am using Flask framework and python as well.

Using `display: none;` in CSS when loaded you cannot see the table and the h2 tag is placed right below it.

[intial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3dvU.png)

But when you start typing in the table displaces the h2 tag and remains on the screen even when not selected on the search bar.

[after search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLGAn.png)

I would like to have it so the results (from a SQL database) only pop up when something is searched and do not displace other elements. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your tries help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and illustrate the problems your are encountering in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This link explains  [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You probably just need to use CSS to keep the rest of the page from moving down. Give your expanding bit 'position: relative' and give everything below it 'position: absolute'. See https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp for details.

(And Alain is correct. Good questions show the result the asker is getting from their current efforts, and clearly contrast that with the desired result so responders can help map a path from one to the other.)

Comment: @AlainMerigot I have added code that I have tried for clarity. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can try to give you a general answer as I'm not extremely well-versed in SQL. As far as the front end side, I'd take a select tag that gets options injected from a pseudo-live html collection and the old ones removed in the same loop. That list would then be getting consistently updated with the Databases's responses.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick example. I've included both PHP and Node.JS solutions using MYSQL.
Remember to change the database credentials.

*Edit: You just posted the framework and your approach. So makes this post kind of redundant.*

**HTML**

```
<input type="search" onkeydown="populate(this.value)" value="" />
<ul id="searchResults">

</ul>
```

**JS**

```
function populate(string){
    function insertList(object){
        list = document.getElementById('searchResults');

        for(i = 0; i < object.length; i++){
            item = document.createElement('li');
            item.innerHTML = '<a href="#">' + object[i].columnname + '</a>';
            list.appendChild(item);
        }

        results = document.getElementById('searchResults');
        if(results.childNodes.length == 0){
            results.style.display = 'none';
        }else{
            results.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }

    xhr = new XMLHTTPRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.readyState == 4){
            insertList(this.responseText)
        }
    }

    xhr.open('POST','/search',true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send('string='+string);
}
```

**CSS**

```
#searchResult {
    display: none;
    width: ; /* I'd make this the same width as your search input */
    position: absolute; /* You can use position: fixed as well*/
    top: ; /* Position this underneath your search input */
    left: ; /* Position this underneath your search input */
}
```

**Server Side - NodeJS**

```
var http = require('http');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var database = mysql.createConnection({
    address: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "database" 
});

database.connect();

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    sql = "SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE ColumnName = ?";
    data = [request.body.string];
    database.query(sql, data, function(error, results){
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        response.write(results);
        response.end()
    });
}).listen(8080);
```

**Server Side - PHP**

```
$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'database');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE ColumnName = '".$_POST['string']."'";
$result = $con->query($sql);
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
print json_encode($rows);
```